# Automation of filling in fields in a telnet session

Tags: c++, qt, automation, telnet

I'm automaticng some telnet tasks in C++ based on this library [QTelnet](https://github.com/silderan/QTelnet). The steps are the following:

1. Login to server via telnet. Telnet asks for user (I put user + [enter]), then asks for password (I put password + [enter]).
2. Telnet shows list of options, that can be selected putting the number + [enter]. Picture example:
   telnet list of options:
   [image: telnet list of options]
3. I select an option, and telnet shows me some fields to fill in, and tells me that when I finish editing press [enter]. Picture example:
   telnet fill fields:
   [image: telnet fill fields]

I have done steps 1 and 2, because it's just replying to the server with the character or word + enter (LF or new line).

I would like to know how telnet handles the data in point 3. How does it separate it? With some special character? Because as I understand it is necessary to differentiate the answer for each field.

**Note:** The images are only for reference.

Comment: `telnet` and the protocol handle almost nothing. Everything you see here is a *function of the terminal*, most likely [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)/VT100 escape codes.

Comment: It could be possible, but what happens after editing and hitting enter? What data does the client send to the server?

Comment: Super easy way to find out: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) or [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org).